# Why Java defaults to not include last value of a given range?

Tags: java, treemap, system-design

I am going through official [TreeMap documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). I see subMap() prototype as:

> `public SortedMap<K,V> subMap(K fromKey, K toKey)` is equivalent to `subMap(fromKey, true, toKey, false)`.

I have seen everywhere, Java does not include the last value of a given range by default? Why was this decision made that default inclusion value for `toKey` will be false (and not true)?

Comment: I think it's for consistency, substring behaves the same, so does sublist.

Comment: my **guess** (this should have been asked to the developers of Java): because *often* in programming languages all indices are zero-based (e.g. arrays), so it is in Java - doing so allow doing `subMap(0, map.size())` using `size()` directly without having to subtract `1`

Comment: I like this author's way of thinking about it: https://blog.nelhage.com/2015/08/indices-point-between-elements/

Comment: You might also want to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631078/why-is-substring-method-substringstart-indexinclusive-end-index-exclusive#26631968

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to specify ranges by specifying end-points it's generally best to specify the range as B<=x<E.
At the very least it means you can specify the empty range by B=E.

But when it comes to 'infinite' value spaces it becomes essential.

Suppose I want to specify every string beginning with C?
In the 'end exclusive' model that's B="C" and E="D".
In the 'end inclusive' model that's B="C" and E="CZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ..." where E is some string we've decided is longer than any string we're going to practically encounter.

It also makes it practical to define non-overlapping coverages as [B,E),[E,F) and so on.

*NB: Mathematical convention is that [ indicates >= and ) indicates <*

Some people argue it's a matter of taste. But in practice you can create a partition from ordered values A,B,C,D,E... as [A,B),[B,C),[C,D) without any fiddling around trying to identify (the potentially non-existent or unconstructable) value immediately before B.

It's somewhere between messy and impossible to construct the partition [A,B-e1],[B,C-e2]. Just duck the issue and use half-inclusive intervals!
It normally makes sense to use inclusive-exclusive ranges but the approach works the other way.

Answer (score 1):

This has been "answered" for `String#substring` here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26631968/1571268

> The question about the "Why" may be considered as philosophical or academic, and provoke answers along the line of "That's just the way it is".
>
> [...]
>
> However, regardless of which choice is made, and regardless how it is justified: It is important to be *consistent* throughout the whole API.

Answer (score 0):

this is general in almost all programming languages I guess!
like I see in 'python' and 'C'.

This is kind of a rule of sets(collections) in mathematics. you can imagine this as below:

```
fromKey <= x < toKey
```

eg:

```
0 <= x < 10
```

anyway, if you want to include `toKey` itself in any range, you should do:

```
toKey + 1
```

or

```
toKey ++
```

Comment: I think that the op knows this. The question was why java made this design decision.

Answer (score 0):

Indices in most programming languages start at `0`. Thus, the last element of any linear collection is `size - 1`.

Now, any range is defined as start (inclusive) - end (exclusive), since it makes the code more readable.

**Example**

Let's say you have `"Java"` and you want to split it at the "v".

With this definition, it is very easy:

```
String java = "Java"; // length: 4
int index = java.indexOf("v"); // 2

String start = java.substring(0, index); // from 0 (inclusive) to 2 (exclusive)
String end = java.substring(index); // from 2 (inclusive) to length (exclusive, implicit)

System.out.println(start + ", " + end); // Ja, va
```

Comment: I have changed "all programming languages" to "most programming languages", because there are languages where indices start at 1, and even languages where you can configure the start index.

Comment: Ah yes, like the dialects of BASIC with `OPTION BASE 0` and `OPTION BASE 1`!  A good example of a contemporary 1-based language is R.

Answer (score -1):

in java almost every method to get a sub part of a data structure it goes form the fromkey (included) to the tokey (not included) so what you have to do is do tokey +1 instead of just tokey.
As for example, if we do map.subMap(a,b); we will get the values from indexes a to b-1.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that the op knows this. The question was why java made this design decision.